# Why does my cutoff frequency not match the 3db down point?

Tags: bode-plot, high-pass-filter

My understanding is that the cutoff frequency of this circuit can be calculated simply by:

1/(2*pi*r*c)

I get a cutoff frequency of 15.9kHz

But as is shown in the provided bode plot 15.9kHz is roughly 6dB down...  Why does this not match 3dB down?

[image]

Comment: theres something weird in you schematic, you have the feedback loop to the non-inverting input instead of to the inverting input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that is a 2nd order filter & as such the cutoff frequency is:

\$\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{R_1 C_1 R_2 C_2}}\$  and the rolloff at this frequency  is dependant on the damping factor

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen%E2%80%93Key_topology#Application:_high-pass_filter

Comment: But R1 = R2 and C1 = C2 shouldn't this simplify to what I have?

Comment: For the cutoff frequency yes, but not the rolloff. This is a 2nd order filter and as such depending on the damping factor, the attenuation will be different

Comment: I guess I have more to learn about filters haha.  Thanks!

Comment: @user125621 Your op-amp is upside down, your inverting input and non-inverting input should be swapped.

Comment: For R1=R2=R and C1=C2=C you have a 2nd-order highpass with a POLE FREQUENCY at wp=1/RC . This pole frequency is identical with the 3dB cut-off for a Butterworth response only (quality factor Qp=0.7071). However, in your case we have Qp=0.5. This is a very poor highpass response, which also could be realized with passice RC structures.